# Is there a more effective way to throw card objects into a stack (or maybe something else than a stack)?

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a more effective way to throw card objects into a stack (or maybe something else than a stack) ??
The VALUES goes up to 13
[image: The VALUES goes up to 13]

Comment: paste your code not pictures

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
var suits = (SUITS[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(SUITS));
var values = (VALUES[])Enum.GetValues(typeof(VALUES));
var stack = new Stack<Card>(suits.Length * values.Length);
foreach(var suit in suits)
{
    foreach(var value in values)
    {
        stack.Push(new Card(value, suit));
    }
}
```

?

I'm not sure that `Stack<Card>` is a useful structure here, though; presumably your next step is "shuffle", which requires ad-hoc mutability; a `Card[]` or `List<Card>` might be better for that.

Also: in naming terms... it isn't normal to capitalize the enum names.

Note that `Enum.GetValues` is not "free"; it may be preferable to use a integer loop. For example, if `VALUES` have values from `1` thru `13`:

```
for(int i = 1 ; i <= 13 ; i++)
{
     VALUES value = (VALUES)i;
     // ...
}
```